# Major difference between SAS Studio and SAS Enterprise

Tags: sas

I have been doing practices and exercising in SAS Studio for sometime. In addition to the fact that SAS Studio is free and better-looking, is there any other difference makes SAS Studio a better choice than SAS Enterprise?

Aside from HTML, running in the cloud, is there any functional difference? Or is there any specific task can be done with more efficiency with either platform?

Comment: SAS Studio is no more free than Enterprise Guide.  It is offered with the free SAS University Edition, but that has limitations on what it can be used for (non-commercial uses, and limited in those).  Both SAS Studio and Enterprise Guide are free options to use with your Base SAS subscription (which is certainly not free).

Comment: Separately - this isn't specific enough to be a good question; it's still in [gorilla vs. shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) territory in my book.  If you're trying to work out what is better for a particular purpose, state the particular purpose here.  Focus this on what specifically your reason for asking is and your use case.  A general survey of two IDEs is far too broad for Stack Overflow and far too broad to get a truly good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several different implementations of SAS Studio, the On Demand version for Academics, the SAS University Edition as well as a version that companies can use to access their server. Each has different limitations. EG is more powerful in my opinion.

However, if they're both installed such that you're accessing a remote server they'll be more equivalent.

SAS UE is limited as well to the packages licensed, for example it does not support SAS Graph. Additionally, it runs on a VM which has limitations on what you can do. And most importantly - the licensing. SAS UE is designed primarily for learning. If you want to consult or implement in your workplace you'll need the full license and then can choose between EG and Studio.

The brand new FAQ also lists a few comparisons:
http://support.sas.com/software/products/sasstudio/faq/SASStudio_vsEG.htm

[image: Chart detailing comparison between EG and Studio]

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the SAS Studio interface is nice and clean but SAS EG has many features that are missing in SAS Studio.  One very useful one for novices is the wizard that does proc tabulate code:  Tasks > Describe > Summary Table